# mapping two identical objects

Tags: c#, object, reflection, mapping

I have two objects(classes) with exact properties. say :

```
class class1
{
  public string prop1{get;set;}
  public string prop2{get;set;}
}

class class2
{
    public string prop1{get;set;}
    public string prop2{get;set;}
}
```

I want to map these classes using reflection, I have already used [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and it doesn't work for my situation, as I have object inside object....

When using reflection I need to pass the property name and i don't want to do this one by one is there other way:

```
PropertyInfo propinfo = listToReturn.GetType().GetProperty(nameofproperty);
```

**EDIT::**

Here is what i have tried with automapper:

```
 internal static DTO_objectclass  ConvertFOS(objectclass q)
        {
            DTO_objectclass  resultsToReturn = new DTO_objectclass();

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<objectclass , DTO_objectclass  >();

            resultsToReturn = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<objectclass , DTO_objectclass>(q);

            return resultsToReturn;
        }
```

this works until it comes to a property where I have something like this in objectclass :

```
property class3 parentClass{get; set;}
```

and in DTO_objectclass  i got :

```
 property guid parentClass{get; set;}
```

where i get exception of failed to convert..

```
Trying to map System.Guid to parentclient.\nUsing mapping configuration for DTO_objectclass   to objectclass \nDestination property: ParentClass\nException of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
```

Comment: Why would you do that, that's a waste of code.

Comment: don't do this, it's pre-mature optimization, using reflection would slow down your performance

Comment: Why don't you post your Automapper problem so someone can help with that instead of trying to reinvent what it already does?

Comment: so how would i do it then

Comment: @IanMercer will edit my post and add automapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception explains the issue. AutoMapper can't convert a GUID to a ParentClass. AutoMapper will assume that two properties/fields with the same name will be of the same type in the absence of better information.

To overcome this, you'll need to write a conversion method. If that method were called `ConvertGuidToParentClassInstance`, for example, you could then write a mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTO_objectcass, objectclass>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.parentClass)
    .MapFrom(src => ConvertGuidToParentClassInstance(src.parentClass));
```

With such a mapping in place, AutoMapper can handle this case.

Comment: hi what if i have two properties with parent classes? would that be in same createmap

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. It can be done in the same `CreateMap` call. It's a fluent interface, so you can chain `ForMember` to your heart's content.